# I'm not sure I understand the stoichiometry of this mechanism

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, stoichiometry, organometallic-compounds

I was going through the experimental mechanism of nickelocene synthesis, and I looked through the notes and it said that there would be $\frac12$ $\ce{NiCl2}$.  I'm sort of confused by the $\frac12$.  It may be the fact I'm pretty sleep deprived and missing something.

[image]

Comment: It's just a matter of stoichiometry - since there are 2 Cp ligands for each Ni, you have to add 0.5 equivalents of Ni to the Cp ligand you already prepared. BTW, KCl2 doesn't exist, so you are probably pretty sleep deprived :p There's only one equivalent of Cl- in 0.5 NiCl2.

Comment: @orthocresol You are correct!   Yes, I am such an idiot! But it might be because I was very tired yesterday xD!  Thank you very much for the clarification!